# Why past simple whereas present perfect should be used instead?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

In "Game of Thrones", season 6, episode 4 there is a scene when one guy spots that his mate is sick (his hand is getting rotten) and gets worried about it. But the mate says: "Don't worry. I didn't touch you".

Why didn't he say: "I haven't touched you [yet]?"

I know that sometimes in American English we use simple past whereas in British English present perfect should be used.

Comment: As you say, in British usage the perfect would be more common there, and the simple past sounds distinctly American to me.

Comment: Either tense is appropriate. With the simple past the speaker is referring to a specific time in his memory. "I didn't touch you (at that period I am thinking of)". In the present perfect "I haven't touched you" it means at no time in the past until the present (now) have I touched you. There is no guarantee that it might not occur sometime in the future but at this very precise moment in time, you have not been touched by me. For more emphasis the speaker could say "I have *never* touched you (when my hand was infected/rotting)."

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a12952%20%22present%20perfect%22%20past this user  never gets it wrong. He's simply the best, it's a pity he has stopped posting.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another example might clarify.  Let's say you came home and found that your computer monitor wasn't at the same spot on the desk as when you last saw it.  You're more likely to ask "Did anyone touch my desk?" and it's more likely that the response would be, say from your room mate, "No mate, I didn't touch your stuff".
If the room mate's response were "No, I haven't touched your stuff", it could mean that he is planning to touch it in the future.

But then again, the more I look at it, the more I'm convinced that the alternate form of the question and response are equally meaningful
"Has anyone touched my desk?" "No mate, I haven't even been in your room"

Comment: The first section of your answer made me think that maybe there was a similar thing in the mentioned scene of "Game of Thrones". If the guy said: "I haven't touched you yet" it would mean that he's planning to do it in the future but probably it wasn't his intention. But please also read the comments below the answer of Shashi Kumar Raja. They also clarify a lot :)

Answer (score -4):

Please see this image to clarify your query-
[image]

Comment: So this answer makes me even more confused as I think that the present perfect should be used. It is because the sick guy has not touched the other guy since the moment he got sick until now!

Comment: Analyse the sentence from the point of view of the act of touching.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get it now. Because normally we say: "I haven't seen that movie", "I haven't done this and that", "I haven't ridden a bike this year" e.t.c. So I still believe it should be "I haven't touched you yet"...

Comment: The touching incident by Ser Jorah(Yes, I am a big fan of the series and book.) is done in the past and he doesn't plan on repeating it in the present or future.

Comment: Thank you Shashi! I knew that there must be something related to some deeper context. Thanks a lot! Now it's clear!

Comment: This is an oversimplification, and what's more, it's inaccurate. In the sentence **"I have been to Rome"** the action of going to Rome and coming back home is, to put it in your words: **over, done, finished!** and yet in BrEng the present perfect tense is used.